# Complement calculations - I don't get the expected results?

Tags: arithmetic, binary, number-systems

I've just started to study complement calculations and I don't understand why I don't get the correct result.

I need to do $47 - 63$ in complement, using $8$ bits.

$47$ is $00101111$ and $-63$ is $11000001$. $47 - 63$ is $47 + (-63)$, so if I would do an addition for those numbers I thought I'd get $-16$, but I don't.

If I add $00101111$ and $11000001$ I get $11110000$ which is not $-16$.

What is flawed in my logic and how can I calculate $47-63$ properly?

Comment: 1111000 is 7 bits, but you are using 8 bits? You probably have lost a bit somewhere in the addition.

Comment: @mathreadler sorry, it was a typo. the result is 11110000

Comment: And if you add 10000 to it you get?

Comment: @mathreadler why would I need to add that? I don't really understand

Comment: Okay. Then what is $-16$? Also, do you have a table of $-1$ down to $-16$?

Comment: 10000 is 16. If for a number you add 16 to it and the sum becomes 0, that is the number -16.

Comment: You used the Two's Complement of $+63$ to represent $-63$, and $11110000$ is the correct representation of $-16$ using Two's Complement. I'm not sure why you think it's wrong.